# React-navigation: nesting stack navigator and tab navigator inside switch navigator results in 2 headers

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, tabnavigator

I am using a combination of tab navigator, stack navigator, and switch nagivator in my react native app with `react-navigation`. Note that I have to put each screen of the tab navigator inside its own stack navigator in order to use the built in header feature.

The functionalities work. But I end up getting 2 headers for `Feed` and `Profile` pages, like this:

[image: screenshot]

I just want each screen to have its own header and the comment screen to have a back button. I know the code is not very clean and putting all these navigators inside each other uses a lot of overhead. So what is the best way to achieve this?

App.js

```
const FeedScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  FeedStack: {
    screen: feed,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Feed"
    }
  }
});

const ProfileScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  ProfileStack: {
    screen: profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "My Profile"
    }
  }
})

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: { screen: FeedScreenStack },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreenStack }
});

const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ 
  Tab: TabStack,
  Comments: { 
    screen: comments, 
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Comments"
    },
  }
});

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Home: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStack);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you want the `Comments` screen to have its own header (like all the other screens) and a back button. **What specifically should it go back to?** Understanding the structure of the navigation will make it easier to design.

It would be cleaner to have your `AppStack` actually just be your `TabStack`. Adding in the `Comments` screen on the same level as `TabStack` likely isn't helping your multiple header issue.

Here I show how you could cut out `AppStack` entirely and nest `Comments` in either the `Profile` of `Feed` tabs, depending on your need.

```
const FeedScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  FeedStack: {
    screen: feed,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Feed"
    }
  },
  // if you want Comments to go back to "Feed"
  Comments: { 
    screen: comments, 
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Comments"
    },
  }
});

const ProfileScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  ProfileStack: {
    screen: profile,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "My Profile"
    }
  },
  // if you want Comments to go back to "Profile"
  Comments: { 
    screen: comments, 
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Comments"
    },
  }
})

const TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Feed: { screen: FeedScreenStack },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreenStack }
});

const MainStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Home: TabStack,
    Auth: AuthStack
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainStack);
```

However, if you want `Comments` to in fact live above `Profile` and `Feed`, you should either make it its own tab, or change it into a `Modal` on the top level. Let me know if this is more like what you need and I can post more specifics!

Comment: This is great but what if I want to always have the tabstack at the bottom of the app? except for when it is in `Auth` view?

Comment: That is the exact behavior of my app, and the above code should result in just that! There will be no tab bar on the `AuthStack` because it is on the same level as `TabStack`, but NOT inside of it. And there will be tabs (at the bottom) for all of `TabStack`, which is the entire rest of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify AppStack Like this:

Edited:

i forgot to include it inside navigationOptions. try.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ 
  Tab: {
    screen:TabStack,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      headerMode: 'none',

      // or this

      header: null
     })
  },
  Comments: {
    screen: comments, 
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: "Comments"
    },
  }
},
);
```

Comment: This will not work because it overwrites the header of `Comments `

Comment: Doesn't work, still 2 headers. `headerMode:'none'` or `header:null` have no effect